# Default container arguments

Tags: c++, stl

The following header works with the commented part as expected when I call the function bat with no arguments:

```
class Test
{
 public:

  void bat(std::vector<int> k = std::vector<int>()) {}
  //void cat(std::map<int, std::vector<int> > k = std::map<int, std::vector<int> >()) {}

};
```

But when I try using the cat function in the header:

```
class Test
{
 public:

  void bat(std::vector<int> k = std::vector<int>()) {}
  void cat(std::map<int, std::vector<int> > k = std::map<int, std::vector<int> >()) {}

};
```

I get:

```
test.h:14: error: expected ',' or '...' before '>' token
test.h:14: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 4)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_map.h:92: error: provided for 'template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare,\
 class _Alloc> class std::map'
test.h:14: error: default argument missing for parameter 2 of 'void Test::cat(std::map<int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::less<int>, std::all\
ocator<std::pair<const int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >)'
```

How come? And are there easy workarounds for this? hopefully not requiring a pointer type change in the interface?

This is my full header:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
 public:

  //void bat(std::vector<int> k = std::vector<int>()) {}
  void cat(std::map<int, std::vector<int> > k = std::map<int, std::vector<int> >()) {}

};


#endif
```

so all the right includes are there. My version of GCC is terribly outdated (well not at home, ill try it at home too) - but at work it's 4.1.2

Comment: Smells like a GCC bug -- [fails with 4.3.4](http://ideone.com/alZRI), [works with 4.5.1](http://ideone.com/6Ppze). What version are you using?

Comment: This compiles fine, did you include `<map>`?

Comment: The error message would point to 4.1.2, with `<map>` included.

Comment: This compiles fine on GCC 4.6.3.

Comment: @Mat, yes this is version 4.1.2 of gcc - do you know what bug this is about or where I can read more about it? Also..if I can't upgrade compiler, is a pointer the way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code looks OK, but fails on gcc 4.3.4, see [here](http://ideone.com/nC8sj), but compiles fine with 4.6 onwards (I haven't tested 4.4 or 4.5). So it looks like the workaround is to use a newer gcc.

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>

class Test
{
 public:

  void bat(std::vector<int> k = std::vector<int>()) {}
  void cat(std::map<int, std::vector<int> > k = std::map<int, std::vector<int> >
()) {}

};

int main() {

}
```

Concerning default parameters, it may be an idea to drop them altogether:

```
class Test {
 public:

  void bat(std::vector<int> k) {}
  void bat() {}
  void cat(std::map<int, std::vector<int> > k) {}
  void cat() {}
};
```

otherwise, you couple the default parameters to the interface, meaning you cannot change them without requiring re-compilation of all client code.

Comment: The real case scenario is I had a function which differed on whether it took a final container or not..the overload had quite a bit of duplicate code and was very annoying to maintain, but I realized that if the optional final container was empty, it flowed through rather seamlessly to be the version without it, so I merged both overloads and default argumented the final container to an empty one..I think a workaround might be to provide the overload without it, but merely forward the call with an empty container to the only implementation.

Comment: @PalaceChan yes, that sounds like a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted seems fine, so I'm going to turn on my Psychic Debugger module.

Did you:

```
#include <vector>
```

...in your header?

Comment: Yea I did, this is looking more and more like that bug people are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

From the other posts here, it looks like it could be a compiler problem, in which case, you can get around it by using a `typedef` instead of the map type directly.

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>

class Test
{
 public:
  typedef std::map<int, std::vector<int> > MyMap;

  void bat(std::vector<int> k = std::vector<int>()) {}
  void cat(MyMap k = MyMap()) {}

};

int main()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is C++ core Defect Report 325 http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#325

GCC 4.4 implements the suggested (but not yet official) resolution of the DR, see http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57#c36