# default parameter for std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >

Tags: c++

This is my code

```
void push(const PetModel& petModel, const std::string& host, UInt8 side,
     bool full = false, const std::string& master = "", 
     const std::vector<std::pair<UInt8, UInt8> >& skill
              = std::vector<std::pair<UInt8, UInt8> >());  // This is the error Occur
```

and the compiler said:

```
 error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘>’ token
 error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
```

I use Gcc 4.1.2 in SLES. I write a demo, the demo works. is that a bug of gcc?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>


void fun(int a , int b , int c, int d = 0, int e = 0,          
         int f = 0, const std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >& v = std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >()) {
}


int main() {
  fun(1, 2, 3);
}
```

This is the demo.

Comment: Please: Ask a question. Even if you think that it's obvious what you ask for, the question mark helps.

Comment: What about a snippet of what works and what does not?

Comment: He wants to know how to set a default value for the last parameter to his function.

Comment: At what line and column does the error happen?

Comment: Ok, there is gcc-4.3.4 that goes with your example with no complains (http://ideone.com/9eVSU). So I suppose that you're somewhere lost `UInt8` type definition.

Comment: @PaulManta I know what he asks for, but that doesn't mean the question is good. Asking good questions is the key to getting good answers. I do this, because most programming questions which deal with compiler messages can be resolved without external help just by coming up with a proper question and removing stuff from the question which isn't necessary.

Comment: The demo could compiled under gcc-4.1.2.There is noting wrong about UInt8 because I create a static object and pass it to the last argument as a default paramter, It works.

Comment: Where and how is `UInt8` defined?

Comment: I get the answer from here. It's a bug.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640227/default-container-arguments